# Eliezer did not know that he should praise Hashem first and then pray?

Tags: tefilla, parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

Rav Simloi in the [Gem Brochos 32a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=32&format=text)  says

> לעולם יסדר אדם שבחו של הקב"ה ואחר כך יתפלל  A person should always
>   praise Hashem first and then pray.

We learn it from Moshe Rabeinu. Why did not Eliezer know this principle?

Eliezer [Braishis 24 (11, 12)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219) went to find a wife for Yitzchak and prayed to Hashem without any praise beforehand.

> 11 And he made the camels kneel outside the city beside the well of
>   water, at eventide, at the time the maidens go out to draw water.  
>   12 And he said, "O Lord, the God of my master Abraham, please cause to
>   happen to me today, and perform loving kindness with my master,
>   Abraham.

Comment: Eliezer lived before Moshe. Why would he know it?

Comment: Yoma 28b:
Eliezer taught Avrohom's Torah to others; he was דולה ומשקה מתורתו של רבו לאחרים 
and אמר רב קיים אברהם אבינו כל התורה כולה שנאמר עקב אשר שמע אברהם בקולי וגו Avrohom kept the whole Torah.

But see sabbahillel's answer. We have to ask Rabbiner Hirsch why Rav Simloi learns it from Moshe and not from Eliezer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> יב וַיֹּאמַר | יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵי אֲדֹנִי אַבְרָהָם הַקְרֵה נָא לְפָנַי
>   הַיּוֹם וַעֲשֵׂה חֶסֶד עִם אֲדֹנִי אַבְרָהָם
>
> 12 And he said, "O Lord, the God of my master Abraham, please cause to
>   happen to me today, and perform loving kindness with my master,
>   Abraham

Rav Hirsch says that the first part of the statement is the praise of Hashem that precedes a bracha.

> Thou, Who art not only the old old Creator Who laid the foundations of
>   the world thousands of years ago, but Who ar still מחיה every
>   approaching moment, makes it come into existence, Whom I have quite
>   specially learnt to know as such in the experiences of the life of my
>   master, the further continuation of whose life is the matter her
>   concerned at the present moment:

Thus, he starts the request with the acknowledgement and praise of Hashem as the Creator of the world and the source of the Hashgacha Pratis in the life of Avraham and who had brought him there by Kefitzas Haderech (shortening of the way) so that the fruits he carried were still fresh.